RollupError error: how to get the faulting file?
I'm using vite v5 (and thus rollup under the hood) to bundle a library.
When I build my project I get:
✓ 1430 modules transformed.
x Build failed in 52.11s
error during build:
RollupError: Could not resolve "./test/RequireJsMock" from "./test/RequireJsMock?commonjs-external"
file: ./test/RequireJsMock?commonjs-external
    at getRollupError (file:///C:/path/to/myproject/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.14.3/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:392:41)
    at error (file:///C:/path/to/myproject/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.14.3/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/parseAst.js:388:42)
    at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///C:/path/to/myprojectt/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.14.3/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:18939:24)
    at file:///C:/path/to/myproject/node_modules/.pnpm/rollup@4.14.3/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:18899:26 

This code is not part on my own code, but probably a faulty code in the dependencies.
How to get which file is the faulty one?
The stack trace relates to rollup engine itself, not to the file causing trouble.
I tried to extend the vite.config.ts file to augment the log:
export default defineConfig({
    logLevel: "info",
    build: {
        rollupOptions: {
            logLevel: "debug",
            onLog: (level, log, defaultHandler) => {
                console.log("onLog", level, log);
                defaultHandler(level, log);
            },
            onwarn: (warning, defaultHandler) => {
                console.log("onwarn", warning);
                defaultHandler(warning);
            },        
        }
    }
});

Also, tested using -d switch on vite build -d.
But there's no more context in the error.
